# ubuntu 16.04 No Dash, no Launcher, no titlebar

Tags: unity

No Dash, no Launcher, no titlebar. Can open terminal by right click desktop, but cannot move the window. Exsiting answers in [[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears]) have been tried, but not work. I do not have /org/compiz in our computer.
After I attempt to install samba(a dpkg error raise and I remove it), and encouter low graphics when I reboot. After I solve the low graphics problem and enter the desktop, this problem appears.

Comment: Ubuntu version, what led you to this point will be helpful.

Comment: "Exsiting answers in another posts" cool cool.... which ones? links please. this way we can at least fill in the gaps